# Retina sprite icon issue

Tags: retina-display, css-sprites

I'm having a problem with my language switcher retina sprite icon. 
since I've a :before statement for my language switcher and I applied sprite icon style there. I need your help to adjust it for 2x device pixel ratio (retina). here's the code:

```
.l-header #nav > div.v-menu::before {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 23px;
width: 23px;
background-position: 0 -1993px;
left: 20px;
top: 16px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-image: url('../img/sprite-icons-sf04c977769.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}





@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0),
   only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0),
   only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 200/100),
   only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) {
       .l-header #nav > div.v-menu::before {
          background-image:url('../img/sprite@2x.png');
          -webkit-background-size: 0px -3986px;
          -moz-background-size: 0px -3986px;
          background-position: 0px -3986px;
      }
  }
```

I actually have 2x sprite image as well ('../img/sprite@2x.png').

website url: [mywebsite](http://faradid-honar.com)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `@media (min-resolution: ...)`?

Comment: Yes, I already read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398038/retina-sprite-css-not-working) and tried to use those media query styles but didn't work out for me.

Comment: Can you post the full code then, including the media query, so that someone can take a look at what's wrong with it.

Comment: I've just added full code. you can check now.

Comment: Don't you mean `background-position` rather than `background-size` in the media query.

Comment: I changed `background-size` to `background-position` but nothing happend.

Comment: Is there any hint for me?

Comment: Sorry, I  meant to reply earlier, but real life got in the way. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as in your case, the two background images have the right sizes with respect to each other and the sprites are in the right locations in the images, you don't have to recalculate the background position again, it will be done automatically.

All you need to do is specify the background position and background size of the smaller image.

```css
.l-header #nav > div.v-menu {
  position: relative; 
  margin-left:auto;
  width:30px; height:30px;
}

.l-header #nav>div.v-menu::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  background-position: 0 -1993px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 16px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-image: url('http://faradid-honar.com/wp-content/themes/faradid/assets/img/sprite-icons-sf04c977769.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 71px 2157px;  /* this is new */
}

@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 200/100),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2.0) {
  .l-header #nav>div.v-menu::before {
    background-image: url('http://faradid-honar.com/wp-content/themes/faradid/assets/img/sprite@2x.png');
    /* all other properties can remain as they were */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="l-header">
  <div id="nav">
    <div class="v-menu">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```